# Excel to pdf conversion with a footer image

Tags: excel, pdf-generation

I need a way to convert my excel files to pdf that can have any no of rows. but the no of rows per each page is a constant and each page should have an image in the footer. 
an example would be if i have 150 rows and the constants per page is 100 then i need to get a pdf file with two pages and each of these pages should have a footer image?

any idea how I can go about the same. I am thinking about writing a small program for the same. But I need suggestion regarding which tool to use for the conversion depending on the ease of use. 
I am also thinking about maintaining a constants file that feeds in the required details. like no of rows, footer image location, file location  etc.

Thanks. waiting for a reply.

**Edit:**
Well guys I have 1000 of such files and I cant possibly open each one of these files and add footer etc and saving it as pdf. I need to automate this.

Comment: What's the problem with just setting your page breaks, header/footer and margins in Excel (including your image), then "Save As" PDF?

Comment: well these excel files are auto generated and I cant open each one of them and attach footer and then save as pdf. I need a script to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [PDF Converter Services](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html). It provides a web services based interface to carry out the conversion. You can also [specify a watermark](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/06/using-awesome-new-watermarking-features.html) to add an image to the footer of each page.